# C# metro - Background task refresh less than 15 minutes

Tags: c#, background, microsoft-metro, task

I have a `BackgroundTask` to refresh live tile. I use `TimeTrigger` but I need a more quickly refresh than 15 minutes. I read it's impossible, but oficial app Social use it for show a profiles pictures of users friend, so some way must exist.

Can you help me?

Comment: I read somewhere that the 15 minutes is there for a good reason; to prolong device battery life, for example. I also read that if you want to push out notifications more quickly, you need to use Push Notifications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This sample shows you how to do it:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff

It basically creates ScheduledTileNotifications for every minute for the next couple of hours. When that time is up a BackgroundTask creates the ScheduledTileNotifications again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use **tile notification queue**, with it's help you can show up to 5 notifications, as it does the app Social.